# Spring Web Application architecture

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm learning Spring Framework. So I want to build the application which architecture will be good enough. For example my application will be some kind of a social network. I'm using Spring Boot container for this web application.
Is this architecture is correct? I mean scalability, future code support, etc. What are advantages and disadvantages? I want to use REST api and microservices. 1 page = 1 controller = 1 service.

[image: Structure]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 service, 1 controller, 1 page is not a good thing to limit yourself to. You'll find a page may use a whole bunch of different services. Imagine if your facebook profile was one controller. It would be gigantically large, impossible to maintain. Just break downs things as logically as you can. Sometimes it may make sense to have a page which uses multiple controllers, sometimes you could have a controller which handles multiple pages so you don't have 30 really small controllers. I would say if you have a complex page you'll need multiple controllers, if you have allot of very simple pages one controller may handle many of them.

Can I also suggest you don't break things up when you don't need to. All your micro services your planing can just be components in your application. Otherwise you will find you have a massive overhead of maintaining code which just forwards and receives HTTP requests. This could also cost you an extremely valuable tool: Transactions! You will lose transactions, and this could lead to inconsistencies in maintaining data. Keep in mind your just one person. I have been trying to finish a webapp I have been working on which is 95% done and I'm spending 8 hours a day after work, working on it till 2am. Do your self a favor and don't create more work for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with most points of [Snickers3192's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39863466/3798217). Microservices is not something you should plan up front, your application should exist first, a monolith is fine for the beginning. Martin Fowler has written [a good piece about the Microservices yes or no question](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/MicroservicePrerequisites.html). Once your app grows and you see the need for either parts of your application being scaled separately or teams needing to be able to develop independently, then you've got a business case for Microservices (and as you'll see from Fowler's article, you must also be ready to support such an architecture). Right now it's overengineering.

That said: If you start with a monolith and plan to evolve to Microservices later, then you need to pay attention to your dependency tree. Different parts of your application will need to access each other, and that's fine, but make sure you don't introduce circular dependencies, otherwise extracting Microservices later will be a nightmare. Ideally, you can identify service interfaces that you will use, and you implement them locally now, but may later implement them by calling a Rest API.

The pattern you suggest (1 service for 1 controller) maps to the [Backends for Frontends](https://www.thoughtworks.com/radar/techniques/bff-backend-for-frontends) pattern, which can be a good idea, depending on how complex your web site is. If you have many UI components that are shared between controllers, then you'll probably want to embrace another approach, e.g. [Big Pipe](https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/bigpipe-pipelining-web-pages-for-high-performance/389414033919/). But it does make sense to have one controller that bundles everything a given page needs to know and delegates it to the upstream services, independent of whether all of this is on the same machine or in a Microservice architecture.

Lastly: if you do go with Microservices, pay attention to resilience. Use a circuit breaker like Hystrix or an event-driven architecture, otherwise one dying service can take down the entire architecture.